# How to add Truffle signing keys to MacOS keychain

Tags: truffle, ganache, mac-osx

Debated what Stack Exchange to go to for this, but I thought I'd start here since it's related to setting up a local Ethereum dev environment. I downloaded and have been using the Ganache command-line interface to create a local blockchain to develop smart contracts on, but also wouldn't mind having a sweet GUI to look at.

I downloaded the MacOS Ganache desktop app, and after installing it from the .dmg, tried opening it up, getting this error.

```
“Ganache” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
```

I checked the Truffle Suite's [Github page](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache) for Ganache installation, and they mention before building Ganache from a .dmg, to

```
Make sure you have Truffle's signing keys added to your keychain
```

Is this for a particular Truffle product, and where do I find the signing keys to add to my MacOS keychain?

Answer (score 1):

The message is popping up because the Ganache.app from the dmg file has not been correctly signed. This can be checked on MacOS with

```
codesign -v /Application/Ganache.app
```

Actually this should be fixed already according to this issue https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/216

Anyway, you can navigate around this on Mac by opening "System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General" and then click on button "Open Anyway". You'll have to do this directly after the failed Ganache start.